# hyperledger fabric setup with more than one orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have setup a fabric network with more than one orderer and analyzing few scenarios on how it is working. Have two question.

1. One of the advantages of multi orderer network is to avoid a single
   point of failure. So if one orderer fails it has to automatically
   take another orderer into the picture and continue the work. But in
   the actual scenario for peer chaincode invoke through cli we pass
   arguments of orderer and cafile of orderer to make a transaction.
   Here we are passing the orderer info so if the orderer we choose is
   down the transaction will not be done. My question is - this is not
   the objective of multi orderer network so why we need to pass the
   orderer related arguments?
2. I deployed this network with 4 kafka brokers and 3 zookeepers. Even
   after stopping all the three zookeepers the fabric network is giving
   the correct response. What is the significance of zookeeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The point of multiple orderers is to eliminate a single point of
   failure and to allow the ordering service to scale horizontally. The
   peer CLI is really not intended to be used for invokes in a
   production application. Typically, an SDK such as Node or Java would
   be used, and on failure, the invoke would be retried to another
   orderer.
2. The Kafka brokers use Zookeeper to manage leader election, and
   generally orchestrate changes in the Kafka cluster. I would expect
   that with zookeeper down, eventually you will experience problems
   with the cluster. Network may run properly until kakfa doesn't have any issues. But, when kafka gets some issue, it is the Zookeeper which will take care of next steps.